# Select rows that are duplicates on two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have data in a table. There are 3 columns (ID, Interval, ContactInfo). This table lists all phone contacts. I'm attempting to get a count of phone numbers that called twice on the same day and have no idea how to go about this. I can get duplicate entries for the same number but it does not match on date. The code I have so far is below.

```
SELECT ContactInfo, COUNT(Interval) AS NumCalls
FROM AllCalls
GROUP BY ContactInfo
HAVING COUNT(AllCalls.ContactInfo) > 1
```

I'd like to have it return the date, the number of calls on that date if more than 1, and the phone number.

Sample data:

```
|ID      |Interval    |ContactInfo|
|--------|------------|-----------|
|1       |3/1/2017    |8009999999 |
|2       |3/1/2017    |8009999999 |
|3       |3/2/2017    |8001234567 |
|4       |3/2/2017    |8009999999 |
|5       |3/3/2017    |8007771111 |
|6       |3/3/2017    |8007771111 |
|--------|------------|-----------|
```

Expected result:

```
|Interval    |ContactInfo|NumCalls|
|------------|-----------|--------|
|3/1/2017    |8009999999 |2       |
|3/3/2017    |8007771111 |2       |
|------------|-----------|--------|
```

Comment: Also group by Interval.

Comment: If I group by interval, it only returns one result.

Comment: You should add example data and expected output

Comment: Added sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Just as juergen d suggested, you should try to add Interval in your GROUP BY. Like so:

```
 SELECT AC.ContactInfo
    ,       AC.Interval
    ,       COUNT(*) AS qnty
    FROM    AllCalls AS AC
    GROUP BY AC.ContactInfo
    ,       AC.Interval
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I tried that exact code but Access returns only the first result.

Comment: Hmm thats weird. Are you sure the values are identical? No hidden whitespaces or anything? Other than that I can't find a reason for your odd result.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting and typing it; same result. I'm off today so I'll try again on Monday and hopefully come up with the issue.

Comment: Ah oke. Good luck on monday! Enjoy your weekend anyways:)

Answer (score -1):

The code  should  like  this :
select  Interval , ContactInfo, count(ID) AS NumCalls from  AllCalls  group by Interval, ContactInfo having count(ID)>1;

Comment: This has the same issue as Juergen's answer: I only get one result returned.